# SQL Server : trigger on Insert alter input

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am fairly new to SQL Server and I am struggling with creating a trigger that does what I need.

We have a table that before a record is inserted we want to manipulate the input value.

Example table:

```
MyTable 
(   
    [RUID] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [CustomerName] nvarchar(200),
    [CustomerStatus] INT,
    [CustomerType] char(1),
    [OtherFields] nvarchar(100)
)
```

An insert may come in like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([CustomerName], [CustomerStatus], [CustomerType], [OtherFields]) 
 VALUES ('LName~FName', 2, 'A', 'Other Info')
```

We don't have control of the source system doing the insert (a vendor product that is on its way out in a couple years so management doesn't want to spend the sums of money to have them alter it) but we need something like this to happen.

**CustomerStatus** that is inserted to be 2x inserted value

**CustomerType** - Regardless of the value sent we want to be overridden with a value of 'B'

All other columns are left as is.

So with an insert sent with the values in the example above, we would actually want this to end up in the table:

```
'LName~FName', 4, 'B', 'Other Info'
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Specs:

- SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition (Database is in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode though)

Comment: If CustomerType is always 'B', why not just make that column a computed column? Or, are there other cases where you might want to insert a value other than 'B' (which means a trigger will overwrite those too)?

Comment: Good point, but in this case I had simplified the actual issue greatly for example.  

Basically the table is a Queue for automation to process out of we want all requests that enter the queue to be brought into a single status that puts them in waiting until another process comes and checks them for  before processing of the requests continues. Once that batch process has finished then the status will be changed so the automation servers know to process the requests, then the status is yet changed again to mark them as completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need an Instead of trigger. The code would look something like...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Insert_MyTable
ON MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO MyTable ([CustomerName], [CustomerStatus], [CustomerType], [OtherFields])
SELECT [CustomerName]
     , [CustomerStatus] * 2 AS [CustomerStatus]
     ,'B' [CustomerType]
     , [OtherFields]
FROM inserted


END
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.